# How to create custom URL in Struts 2? Like www.twitter.com/goodyzain

Tags: java, jsp, url, struts2, wildcard-mapping

I am working on a project where I want to provide unique URL for each user.

For example:

- `www.SocialNetwork.com/jhon`
- `www.SocialNetwork.com/jasmine`

So far I'm able to achieve this:

- `www.SocialNetwork.com/profiles/jasmine`

here `profiles` is my action where I can get the user name by

```xml
<constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false"/>
<constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>
<constant name="struts.patternMatcher" value="namedVariable"/> 


<action name="profiles/{username}" class="com.example.actions.ViewProfileAction">
  <result name="input">/WEB-INF/jsp/profile.jsp</result>
</action>
```

but I want to achieve something *like* this:

- `www.SocialNetwork.com/jasmine`

Just use *domain name* and *username*.

Like Twitter does:

- `www.twitter.com/username`

How to achieve this?

Comment: So why do you put `profiles/` in front of the action name if you don't want it to be there?

Comment: i dont need profiles to be in URL...for users it should be simple...like Domainname/username...simple one..

Comment: So remove it from action name.

Comment: U mean to tell... http://www.SocialNetwork/jasmine but the problem is jasmine is a username...i dont have any action class so that i can process the name and redirect to his profile page...

Comment: @goodyzian How do you distinguish between user names and and other actions?

Comment: Yeah...that was other case...i will assign them a unique Id...like the username not going to be just Jhon...i will give something like this...Jhon+unique id...like  http://www.SocialNetwork/jasmine$8383992Juuf, Roman C sir i am just finding a way where i can provide Unique urls to every user...:)in simple fashion like domainname/username..is this achievable.??

Comment: Why not if you have only one action in the root namespace that gets the username as a parameter in url?

Comment: like this...<package name="default" extends="struts-default,json-default,jasperreports-default" namespace="profiles"> Or can u tell me How to do this...??

Comment: I made a complete sample for the above. If any one wants please refer [here](http://tech.learnerandtutor.com/custom-url-in-struts2-for-each-user/)

Comment: @Rajesh its mine...:p :p :p

Comment: @goodyzain I accept. But I made that for the new users to understand completely and easily all discussions made here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use named patterns in wildcard mapping then you should configure following in the `struts.xml`:

```xml
<constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>
<constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false"/>
<constant name="struts.patternMatcher" value="regex"/>
```

now assume `com.example.actions.ViewProfileAction` bean has a property `username`, and method `execute` that returns a `SUCCESS` result. Then you can map the action in the root namespace `"/"` configured to your package.

```xml
<action name="{username}" class="com.example.actions.ViewProfileAction">
  <result>/WEB-INF/jsp/profile.jsp</result>
</action>
```

you can get the name in the JSP using OGNL

```xml
<s:property value="username"/>
```

Also note that you should deploy to the root context to have

`your.domain.com/username` mapped to your action.

Comment: I'm getting null action mapping when I follow the same. am I doing anything wrong ?

Comment: Sorry its working for me, I missed entry in the web.xml :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this out. It may work. Use **Freemarker** USE `$`.

```xml
<action name="profiles/${username}" class="com.example.actions.ViewProfileAction">
    <result name="input">/WEB-INF/jsp/profile.jsp</result>
</action>
```

It may work

Comment: it will work fine...i want the URL to look like this... SocialNetwork/jasmine Not Like  SocialNetwork/profiles/jasmine i dont want to call profiles action...in url

Comment: So don't use profiles. use only action name="${username}". it will work for you.

Comment: SocialNetwork is Domain Name,Jasmine is Username...Profiles Is actions name...I dont want user to enter action name which is profiles..i just want them to enter them is Domainname/username NOTE:no action name is called in URL

Comment: i voted your question up. its a nice question. i will work on it.

Comment: How to call this action from the login form? I tried like <s:form> <s:textfield name="username"/> <s:submit/> But it is calling just .action like localhost:8080/CustomURL/.action </s:form>

Comment: @goodyzain that i was telling you yesterday. that remove profiles and use ognl like Roman C sir said. you can see my comments also. and set the action file means java file in class attribute of action tag. jsp remains same as it is.

Comment: @Rajesh here we are using in the Above question <s:form action="{username}"> and struts.xml <action name="{username}">. i think by this you get your answer.

Comment: @Paresh3489227 Thanks. As you mentioned I added but it is not showing the correct url it shows name username in URL. I posted a separate question for that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23819733/how-to-call-custome-url-action-from-form-action). Please suggest.

Comment: @Paresh3489227 Yeh..Paresh You told me that in comments...But i was in confused state..before thinking of Ticking Your Answer RomonC sir told He will Work on this and Posted the Full answer...so i voted your Answer :(

Comment: its okay. i am happy that you got your answer.