# How to call custome URL action from Form action?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, wildcard-mapping

I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780282/how-to-create-custom-urls-with-struts2like-twitterwww-twitter-com-goodyzain) and created a custom URL application. The action is getting called but the url shows with  session id like

`http://localhost:8080/CustomURL%7Busername%7D.action;jsessionid=9C1FB3EB633209C18625BBB40EA61000`

I want simply like `http://localhost:8080/CustomURL/rajesh`

**See my `struts.xml`:**

```xml
<struts>
<constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace"
    value="false" />
<constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true" />
<constant name="struts.patternMatcher" value="namedVariable" />
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="">
        <result name="success">home.jsp</result>
    </action>

    <action name="{username}" class="com.rajesh.struts2.CustomURL"
        method="customUrl">
        <result name="success">welcome.jsp</result>
    </action>

</package>
```

**See my JSP page:**

```xml
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Struts 2 Custom URL</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Struts 2 Custom URL</h1>
    <h3>Enter your name below</h3>
    <s:form action="{username}">
        <s:textfield name="username" />
        <s:submit />
    </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**See java file below:**

```java
public class CustomURL extends ActionSupport {

    private String username;

    public String getUsername() {
        System.out.println("Getter");
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        System.out.println("Setter");
        this.username = username;
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4337790298641431230L;

    public String customUrl() {
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should get rid of action extension, if you don't want user to think their name has an extension.

```xml
<constant name="struts.action.extension" value=",,action"/>
```

Next the pattern matcher should be `regex`.

```xml
<constant name="struts.patternMatcher" value="regex"/>
```

Action mapping

```xml
<action name="/CustomURL/{username}" class="com.rajesh.struts2.CustomURL" method="customUrl">
    <result name="success">welcome.jsp</result>
</action>
```

In the JSP you don't need to use `form` tag, but anchor tag. And use known names.

```xml
<a href="http://localhost:8080/CustomURL/rajesh">Click my name</a>
```

Comment: @Roman C sir i have a doubt. when i use `regex` it is not working. when i use `namedVariable` it is working. why it is happening?

Comment: @Paresh3489227 `regex` pattern matcher might be not available in the struts version you use.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$` before {username}. `$` Stands for `Freemarker`

```
<action name="{username}" class="com.rajesh.struts2.CustomURL" 
 method="customUrl">
```

**[Freemarker Tutorial](http://freemarker.org/)**

**[How to use OGNL Expression Example link](http://www.tutorials4u.net/struts2-tutorial/struts2_ognl_expression_language_example.html)**

```
<s:property value="username"/> for calling username on welcome page.
```

It may help you to get your answer.

Comment: and if still it won't work then please post your action file means your java file in your question.

Comment: It's not working. I added the java file in the question

Comment: <constant name="struts.patternMatcher" value="regex"/> try this

Comment: I tried it is not working with <s:form> tag. because it is not taking dynamically username from textbox. and forward. without form tag in url your domain/anyname it will work you will get success page. @Rajesh

Answer (score 0):

try it..

```
 public String customUrl() {

   HttpServletRequest request=(HttpServletRequest) ActionContext.getContext().get(ServletActionContext.HTTP_REQUEST);
   String url="http://"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+""+request.getContextPath()+"/"+request.getParameter("username");

   logger.info(" Current url : "+url);  //check it here

    return SUCCESS;
 }
```