# How to create a dynamic URL in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, url, dynamic, struts2

I have created form `login.jsp` and when user enter username & password then i want to create URL like : `/companyName/username`.

Example : If company name is `abc` and username is `parth1` then URL is

`"http://localhost:8080/Temp_Central_Emp/abc/parth1/afterLogin.jsp"`

I get `companyName` from the database based on the username.

**File : `login.jsp`:**

```
<s:form action="afterLogin" method="post">
    <s:textfield label="Enter username" key="userId" maxlength="5" size="30" id="userId"/>
    <s:password label="Enter password" key="userPsw" size="30" />
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <img src="<c:url value='simple-captcha.png' />" />
            <br />
            <p>Press F5 for refresh.</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <s:textfield label="Enter code" key="captchaResponse" size="30" />
    <s:submit value="Login" />
</s:form>
```

**File : `struts.xml`:**

```xml
<struts>
<constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/> 
<constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false"/>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<package name="a" extends="struts-default">
 
    <action name="afterLogin" class="com.parth.LoginAction">
        <result name="success">/afterLogin.jsp</result>
    </action>

</package>
```

**File : `LoginAction.java`:**

```
public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport{

private Map<String, Object> session;
private String userId;
private String userPsw;
private String url;

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
@Action(value="{url}/afterLogin")
public String execute() throws Exception {      
    // business logic to insert user into database
    url = "/companyName/" + userId;
    return SUCCESS;
}

 /* Getters and Setters */
}
```

I refer this link but my need is different. [Creating dynamic URL with 2 action parameters in Struts 2 using OGNL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20095769/creating-dynamic-url-with-2-action-parameters-in-struts-2-using-ognl)

I also try code from this link but still i'm not solving it.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780282/how-to-create-custom-urls-with-struts2like-www-twitter-com-goodyzain

Comment: @goodyzain when i add **<constant name="struts.patternMatcher" value="regex"/>** i receive error.

And i also changed my code based on the answer on your question but stil not work.

If you know how to generate dynamic url then please provide me code based on the above question.

Comment: whats the error you are getting when you add Advanced wildCard  <constant name="struts.patternMatcher" value="regex"/> ??

Comment: In browser : **HTTP Status 404 - /Temp_Central_Emp/**  

In console : 
"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load bean com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.PatternMatcher (regex) - [unknown location]"

Comment: @goodyzain In your application what you wrote action name in form?
  <s:form action="?">
  </s:form>

Comment: @goodyzain I successfully transfer the page but in url i receive **/%7Burl%7D** instead of **/companyName/parth**.

Comment: @ParthPatel you should post the stacktrace

Comment: @RomanC can you explain what is stacktrace?
I'm new on struts2.

Comment: @ParthPatel It's what is printed in the console when exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

try to put that **url** variable in your `struts.xml`:

```
<action name="afterLogin" class="com.parth.LoginAction">
    <result name="success">${url}/afterLogin.jsp</result>
</action>
```

and remove your annotation `Action` here:

```
@Override
//@Action(value="{url}/afterLogin") // remove this
public String execute() throws Exception {      
    // business logic to insert user into database
    url = "/companyName/" + userId;
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: thanks.

But i receive error : **HTTP Status 404 - /Temp_Central_Emp/companyName/parth/afterLogin.jsp**

Comment: I think you need to dynamically change your companyName too.

Comment: If you have idea then please edit the above code which you wrote.

Comment: @LKTN.25 How can you determine the location of JSP?

Answer (score 0):

The result should be of redirect action type if you want to change the URL and follow PRG pattern. See [Parameters in configuration results](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Parameters+in+configuration+results):

```xml
<result name="success" type="redirectAction">afterLogin?companyName=${companyName}&userId=${userId}</result>

<action name="afterLogin">
   <result>/afterLogin.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: I use your code in struts.xml but it is not working.

Comment: can you tell me where i write this code in struts.xml

means in the <action> or outside the <action>

Comment: http://struts.apache.org/docs/result-configuration.html

Comment: please descreibe the proper struts.xml file for the given solution.

Comment: After using your code url is **http://localhost:8080/Temp_Central_Emp/afterLogin.jsp?/CompanyName/parth** but i want **http://localhost:8080/Temp_Central_Emp/CompanyName/parth**.  
So where i need to change to get this URL?

Comment: You should use different actions one for logon and another after logon.